# UTC to CST Conversion incorrect using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a small issue with the UTC to CST conversion from the python module, datetime. It seems to take off 5 hours and 51 minutes instead of the even six. See code.

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

time_stamp = '18:42:14'
utc = timezone('UTC')
central = timezone('US/Central')
published_time = datetime.strptime(time_stamp, '%H:%M:%S')
published_gmt = published_time.replace(tzinfo=utc)
published_cst = published_gmt.astimezone(central)
actual_time_published = published_cst.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
print(time_stamp)
print(published_time)
print(published_cst)
print('Time: '+actual_time_published)
```

And the terminal output is:

```
18:42:14
1900-01-01 18:42:14
1900-01-01 12:51:14-05:51
Time: 12:51:14 PM
```

Comment: Do you know which version of time zone data you're using?

Comment: I'd expect US/Central (an alias for America/Chicago) to have an offset of -05:50:36 until November 1883. You're getting a value in 1900, so I agree, it *should* be -6. I wonder at what point it changes...

Comment: Could you change this to a [mcve]? I assume `time` is a list you've got somewhere - it would help me to help you if I could just copy/paste/run the code. (I'm not a Python developer, so the simpler it is, the better.)

Comment: (You do seem to be performing a time zone conversion on *just a time* though, which makes no sense to me. You can *only* do a conversion on a full date and time.)

Comment: Please edit that into the question - comments aren't really suitable for code.

Comment: I will edit the post to something that everyone can test

Comment: @JonSkeet
Sorry, I noticed that. It is edited in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the Python time zone library thinks the UTC offset of US/Central was -05:51 until 1901-12-13T20:45:52Z - that's when it switches to -06:00.

The time zone rules actually have it as -05:50:36 (so 5 hours, 50 minutes and 36 seconds) behind UTC until 1883-11-18T18:00:00Z, at which point it should go to -06:00, so the library is definitely doing the wrong thing.

However, more importantly, you're trying to perform a time zone conversion on *just a time*, which is a bad thing to do. You should *always* perform time zone conversions on full date/time values, because that's the only thing that makes sense. The same time of day will have different offsets on different dates in most time zones.

The IANA time zone database is only really expected to be accurate after 1970 anyway, so even though the library isn't following it properly in 1901, it's possible that the data's wrong for that year anyway. I suspect your real data isn't about 1900, but is about a date rather more recent - at which point both the library and the database are more likely to be correct. So make sure you use the right date, and the problem will (I suspect) go away.

Comment: That is what I did and the problem went away. I have the date part of the timestamp parsed out  earlier in the code but I will do away with it and utilize the full capabilities of datetime. Thanks for your help.